# Opentok screen capture issue

Tags: ios, opentok, tokbox

I am using opentok screen share in my app, I am using the TBscreenCapture method provided by the opentok, the app is working fine in iPhone, but in the iPad the screen capture is returning the view with misplaced frame, the image is like instead of starting from 0,0 it is starting from -100,-100 where 100 is representational figure, so I am not able to see the upper part of the screen transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

This is an iOS camera engine library that allows easy integration of special capture features and camera customization

https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision